# Attribute Error : 'Response' object has no attribute 'css'

Tags: python, scrapy

When I tried this I am getting an `Attribute Error  : 'Response' object has no attribute 'css'`

I tried with this code  :

`response.css('h1.ctn-article-title::text').extract()`

can anyone help please?

i'm trying to get text "Update Primary Care" from below code which is title :

Update Primary Care
          CME

i'm placing my entire code  :

```
response = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'requests' is not defined
import requests
response = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'url' is not defined
url = 'somethingurl'
response = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
response.css('h1.ctn-article-title::text').extract()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'css'
response.css('h1').extract()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'css'
response.css('h1.ctn-article-title::text').extract()
```

Comment: can you add more of the code you're using? How are you sending out the request, and what response are you getting?

Comment: here im placing entire code..what i tried..

Comment: The response object you are using is from Requests library and response you are trying to use is from Scrapy library. You are mixing code from two different libraries and it wont work

Answer (score 3):

As Tarun pointed out in the comments: You are mixing `scrapy` and `requests` code.

If you want to create a scrapy response from requests response you can try:

```
from scrapy.http import TextResponse
import requests

url = 'http://stackoverflow.com'
resp = requests.get(url)
resp = TextResponse(body=resp.content, url=url)
resp.xpath('//div')
# works!
```

See the docs for [requests.Response](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response) and [scrapy.http.TextResponse](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#textresponse-objects) objects.

Comment: may i have Scrapy library and Requests library links to know indetail about those two different libraries...thank you..

Comment: @rajeshbojja sure, check out my edit; I've included links to respective doc pages.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the line where your error occurs expects a CSSResponse object not a normal response. Try to create a CSSResponse instead of the normal Response to resolve the error.

[You can get it here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.TextResponse.css)

More specifically use an HtmlResponse because your response would be some HTML and not plain text. HtmlResponse is a subclass of CSSResponse so it inherits the missing method.

Comment: What exactly is that `CSSResponse` class you refer to? Scrapy doesn't have anything like that...

Answer (score 0):

add this line in your code and it will work fine
remove any imports for requests from any other package.

```
from  scrapy.http import Request
```